# display letter A in mask maskedtextbox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, maskedtextbox

i am just thinking about how to display a letter in a maskedtextbox in VS .net 4. I can set up all letters, except an 'A' because it is used as a dummy for alphanumeric letters in in the mask. I want to display the unity "Ampere" in the mask after the value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backslash to escape special characters. \A will do what you want.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx